# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offset' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offset' of undefined

Before that i was getting same exception for 'top' from same block. I fixed it in one way now, I am getting the error with 'offset'.

Here is my code.

```
var ssSmoothScroll = function() {

    $('.smoothscroll').on('click', function (e) {
        if (this.hash !== "" && this.pathname == window.location.pathname) {
        var target = this.hash;
        // $target    = $(target);


        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var topOffset = 0; //#top should default to 0 so no need to calculate the difference between top and top :)
            if (target != "#top") { //If the target is not "#top", then calculate topOffset 
            var topOffset = $(target).offset().top;
            }
        }
        else{
                var target = this.hash,
                $target    = $(target);

                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();

        }
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, cfg.scrollDuration, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
};
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I think `this` refers to event argument. according to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate_smoothscroll) page @Dez

Answer (score 0):

Because you define `$target` inside the else statement so if it does not go into the else it is undefined.

You need to set `$target` outside of the else

```
if (target != "#top") {
  // you do not set it here
  ...
else{
  var target = this.hash,  // <-- not sure why you are declaring target again....
  $target    = $(target); // you set it here
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead, I think this works

```
var ssSmoothScroll = function() {
  $(".smoothscroll").on("click", function(e) {
    if (this.hash !== "" && this.pathname == window.location.pathname) {
      var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);
      // $target    = $(target);

      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      var topOffset = 0; //#top should default to 0 so no need to calculate the difference between top and top :)
      if (target != "#top") {
        //If the target is not "#top", then calculate topOffset
        topOffset = $(target).offset().top;
      }
      $("html, body")
        .stop()
        .animate(
          {
            scrollTop: $target.offset().top
          },
          cfg.scrollDuration,
          "swing",
          function() {
            window.location.hash = target;
          }
        );
    }
  });
};
```